# executing create-react-app gives an error

Tags: reactjs, npm

I get the following error when I run create-react-app my-new-app. My npm version is 6.1.0 and node version is 8.11.3

```
$ create-react-app my-new-app

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\home\Desktop\Web Development\7. 
React\my-new-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ectories":
{},"dist"                                                                     
:{'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\home\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-
16T12_46_38_1                                                                     
22Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-
scripts                                                                      
has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-new-app / from C:\Users\home\Desktop\Web Development\7. React
Done.
```

Comment: If the problem persist try reinstalling the create-react-app

Comment: I did but I get the same thing again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below command:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Comment: After executing the command, did you try reinstalling create-react-app and then creating the project

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have an **outdated create-react-app** version.

If you have npm 6, then you also have **npx**. Using npx you can just do:

```
npx create-react-app my-new-app
```

And it will use the latest create-react-app, even if you don't have it installed.
Check the [documentation](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#create-react-app-)

Comment: I reinstalled create-react-app and even tried npx but none of them works